# Mysql select record that should have today and tomorrow date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select record that must have two or more entries but should have today and tomorrow date in table. I am saving date in table in date format.

```
SELECT `availibility`.* 
FROM (`availibility`) 
WHERE `property_id`= 8818 
AND (availibility.unavailibility_date between CURDATE() 
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

I am using above query but this will true even one date (today or tomorrow) exists. I want to get such record that should have both dates
for example

```
+---------+----------------+------------+
|   ID    |   property_id  |  Date      |
+---------+----------------+------------+
| 369516  | 8818           | 2013-01-19 |
| 369517  | 8818           | 2013-01-18 |
| 369518  | 8818           | 2013-01-17 |
| 418021  | 8818           | 2013-08-27 |
| 418022  | 8818           | 2013-08-28 |
| 418022  | 8818           | 2013-08-29 |
| 418022  | 2001           | 2013-07-29 |
| 418022  | 2001           |2013-07-30  |
+---------+----------------+------------+
```

8818 property should come in record set because both date exists here

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT property_id
FROM yourtable
WHERE date IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY property_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date)=2
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a85ea/1).

Comment: this would not give a valid result when multiple records exist for the same property_id and Date. So make sure your table has only one record per property_id / Date

Comment: Yes there is one record for property with one date

Comment: I am adding where property_id in (multi IDs) before where in query but it is returning just one record where as there are multiple property that have true records set

Comment: Got answer need to add group by before having

Comment: @ErikBaan i'm counting distinct, so it should give the correct result even in there are more than one record per property_id / date, but maybe in that case a join could be faster

Comment: @Farhan yes sorry initially I've forgot a group by but i've fixed it

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you are only interested in the date, not the date and time then you can use CURDATE instead of NOW:

```
CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

your query should be

```
SELECT `availibility`.* 
FROM (`availibility`) 
WHERE `property_id`= 8818 
AND (availibility.unavailibility_date between CURDATE() 
AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY // change here
```

Comment: Can you write complete query. I am unable to understand what you want to say.

Comment: look up my answer now..try it

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN to make sure the second record exists:

```
SELECT `availibility`.* 
FROM `availibility`
JOIN `availibility` AS availibility_tomorrow ON availibility_tomorrow.property_id =     availibility.property_id AND availibility_tomorrow.unavailibility_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE    (),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
WHERE `property_id`= 8818 AND availibility.unavailibility_date = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood this good...

```
SELECT `property_id`, count(*) as no
FROM (`availibility`) 
WHERE `property_id`= 8818 
AND (availibility.unavailibility_date=CURDATE() 
OR availibility.unavailibility_date=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
having no =2
```