# MySQL CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY not returning as should

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am stumped!

I have a table that has a field `job_date_start`  --  And the DataType is set to `DATETIME`

If I `SELECT job_date_start FROM table;` from my table the output is:

```
+---------------------------+
|      job_date_start       |
+---------------------------+
|    2021-02-26 12:00:00    |
+---------------------------+
```

IF I `SELECT NOW();` from the same table I get:

```
+---------------------------+
|           NOW()           |
+---------------------------+
|    2021-02-25 17:41:01    |
+---------------------------+
```

Why then, when I use the following, am I returning and empty result?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE job_date_start = curdate() + interval 1 day;
```

Per MANY Stack Overflow questions [LIKE THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485577/mysql-select-record-that-should-have-today-and-tomorrow-date) my syntax is correct ..  I am not understanding something.

Comment: When comparing dates with datetimes, the datetime is not automatically reduced to a date, but the date is extended to a datetime with its time set to 00:00:00. You don't get the row returned because `timestamp '2021-02-26 12:00:00' <> timestamp timestamp '2021-02-26 00:00:00'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner -- That makes sense now -- So what is the easiest way to `SELECT` "tomorrow" regardless of the time?  I'd like to select the next day even if  `NOW()` is `2021-02-25 23:59:59` and `job_date_start` is `2021-02-26 01:01:00`  ..

Comment: Gordon's first query is what I'd usually use, because with loads of days in the table and an index on the datetime column, the DBMS could run the query really fast, because it could find the few rows quickly, just like we find last names quickly in a telephone book, because they are indexed (i.e. entries are sorted by last name). Gordon's other query has the advantage of being easier to read. But it can be much slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`job_date_start` seems to have a time component.  You need a date range or just the date:

```
WHERE job_date_start >= curdate() + interval 1 day and
      job_date_start < curdate() + interval 2 day ;
```

Or:

```
WHERE DATE(job_date_start) = curdate() + interval 1 day
```

The first is safer for indexes.

Comment: OK totally makes sense as to why that was happening ..  I used the latter since it looks much cleaner ..  And I am using it as a notification .. No Indexes involved